# How can I output only a certain number of digits after a decimal place in a JTextComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, jtextcomponent

I am using both `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s, and need to be able to truncate my doubles to two decimal places when they are displayed by the application.

How can I perform this truncation, preferably without switching to `JFormattedTextField`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class. [Here](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/java-formatting-to-a-fixed-number-of-decimal-places.html) is an explanation

Answer (score 2):

Prefer the Swing `JFormattedTextField` instead; see the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).